# how to find data from mongodb collection in desending order?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Suppose this is a collection named books in mongodb and the data are as follows.Here I ignore _id. please provide a simple query for finding all books from database where the most costly book's document will comes first.

```
>{
    "name":"A",
    "cost":100
 }
 {
    "name":"B",
    "cost":1000
 }
 {
    "name":"F",
    "cost":400
 }
 {
    "name":"E",
    "cost":400
 }
 {
    "name":"Z",
    "cost":800
 }
```

My expected result will be:

```
>{
     "name":"B",
     "cost":1000
 }
 {
     "name":"Z",
     "cost":800
 }
 {
     "name":"E",
     "cost":400
 }
 {
     "name":"F",
     "cost":400
 }
 {
     "name":"A",
     "cost":100
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
  db.books.find({},{"name":1,_id:0,"cost":1}).sort({"cost":-1})
```

Comment: I think this is helpful, thanks

Comment: @KoushikMondal if your problem is solved then please choose correct ans and up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

please use :  .sort({cost:-1}) in your query for showing decending order of collection.

Full query will be :

For node.js :

```
books.find({}).sort({"cost":-1}).exec(function(err,data){

})
```

or

```
db.books.find().sort({"cost":-1})
```